# Parallel processing of arrays using ExecutorService and arrayCopy()

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I have a variety of different algorithms which are each resource intensive, and which each have to be processed on millions of inputs.  I would like to divide the inputs into blocks, then have the blocks processed in parallel, and then finally have the results assembled into a single output array in correct order.

I have been doing research on the matter, and the consensus seems to be that I should use `ExecutorService` and `arraycopy()`.  However, I am not sure how to determine the optimal number of threads to create, and I do not know how to structure the code in a way that eliminates the risk of bugs.  It would be nice if I knew that each thread was terminated after it creates its resulting array.  Finally, the code I wrote below is also giving me a null pointer error.

How can I edit the code below so that it accomplishes my above stated goals as fast as possible, while eliminating the risk of bugs?  It would be nice if the code below could run in 5 or 10 milliseconds. The random numbers in the array are nothing more than placeholders to serve as a benchmark to compare threading options.  I do not need to optimize the random number generation because my actual algorithms have nothing to do with random number generation.

Here is my work in process:

```java
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class ParallelArrays {
    private static final int numJobs = 5;
    static int numElements = 1473200;
    static int blockSize = 300000;
    static int remaining;
    String number;
    static int[][] data2D = new int[numJobs][];
    static int[] data1D;
    static int size;
    static int currIdx;
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        remaining = numElements-blockSize;
        // create a pool of threads, 10 max jobs will execute in parallel
        ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        // submit jobs to be executing by the pool
        for (int i = 0; i < numJobs; i++) {
            currIdx = i;
            System.out.println("This coming iteration would leave us with remaining, blockSize: "+remaining+", "+blockSize);
            if(remaining>=0){System.out.println("blockSize is: "+blockSize);}
            else{
                blockSize = (blockSize+remaining);
                remaining = 0;
                System.out.println("else blockSize is: "+blockSize);
            }
            System.out.println("After iteration, remaining, blockSize are: "+remaining+", "+blockSize);
            threadPool.submit(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Random r = new Random();
                    data2D[currIdx] = new int[blockSize];
                    for(int j=0;j<data2D[currIdx].length;j++){
                        data2D[currIdx][j] = r.nextInt(255)*r.nextInt(255)*r.nextInt(255);
                    }
                }
            });
            remaining -= blockSize;
        }
        //Now collapse data2D into a 1D array
        data1D = new int[numElements];
        int startPos = 0;
        for(int k=0;k<numJobs;k++){
            System.out.println("startPos is: "+startPos);
            //arraycopy(Object src, int srcPos, Object dest, int destPos, int length);
            System.out.println("k is: "+k);
            System.out.println("data2D[k].length is: "+data2D[k].length);
            System.arraycopy(data2D[k], 0, data1D, startPos, data2D[k].length);
            startPos += data2D[k].length;
        }
        threadPool.shutdown();
        System.out.println("Main thread exiting.");
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Elapsed time is: "+(endTime-startTime));
    }
}
```

### Edit

In response to Ralf H's suggestions, I have edited my code as follows.  It is still throwing the same null pointer exception, which I will include again below.  How can I get this to run without throwing the null pointer exception?

```java
package myPackage;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class ParallelArrays {
    private final static int numJobs = 5;
    static int numElements = 1473200;
    static int blockSize = 300000;
    static int remaining;
    String number;
    static int[][] data2D = new int[numJobs][];
    static int[] data1D;
//  static int size;
    static int currIdx;
    static int numAdded = 0;
        
    public static void main(String args[]) {runAlgorithm();}
    
    static void runAlgorithm(){
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        remaining = numElements-blockSize;
        ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        for (int i = 0; i < numJobs; i++) {// submit jobs to be executing by the pool
            currIdx = i;
            if(remaining<0){//last block will be smaller than the rest
                blockSize = (blockSize+remaining);
                remaining = 0;
            }
            final int fCurrIdx = i;
            threadPool.submit(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Random r = new Random();
                    data2D[fCurrIdx] = new int[blockSize];
                    System.out.println("fCurrIdx is: "+fCurrIdx);
                    for(int j=0;j<data2D[fCurrIdx].length;j++){
                        data2D[fCurrIdx][j] = r.nextInt(255)*r.nextInt(255)*r.nextInt(255);
                    }
                    numAdded += 1;
                }
            });
            remaining -= blockSize;
        }
        //Now collapse data2D into a 1D array
        data1D = new int[numElements];
        System.out.println("numAdded, data2D.length is: "+numAdded+", "+data2D.length);
        int startPos = 0;
        for(int k=0;k<numJobs;k++){
            System.out.println("startPos is: "+startPos);
            //arraycopy(Object src, int srcPos, Object dest, int destPos, int length);
            System.out.println("k, data2D["+k+"].length are: "+k+", "+data2D[k].length); // NullPointerException here
            System.arraycopy(data2D[k], 0, data1D, startPos, data2D[k].length);
            startPos += data2D[k].length;
        }
        threadPool.shutdown();
        System.out.println("Main thread exiting.");
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Elapsed time is: "+(endTime-startTime));
    }
}
```

Here is the stack trace for the null pointer error being thrown by the revised code:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException  
    at myPackage.ParallelArrays.runAlgorithm(ParallelArrays.java:52)  
    at myPackage.ParallelArrays.main(ParallelArrays.java:19)
```

I think the problem is that the code needs to use a Future object along with the `ExecutorService`.  But I am not sure of the syntax for this specific code.

Answer (score 3):

I think ForkJoinPool is better for this task. It's designed for efficient parallel processing, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html.

Comment: +1 and Thank you for offering a constructive suggestion.  I am using Java 6 because I do not want to force users to download the newer versions of Java.  ForkJoinPool only runs on Java 7 and the upcoming Java 8, unless I force users to download the add on package JSR-166.  Are you able to make suggestions regarding my ExecutorService code?  I would really appreciate a fresh set of eyes looking at it, as it was causing me trouble today.

Comment: I have isolated the location of the cause of the null pointer error, and have highlighted the offending block of code in an edit to my original posting above.  Do you know how I can get it to stop creating a null pointer error?  I think the problem is that threadpool is not running within the i=0 through 4 loop, even though the offending segment of code does seem to be within the correct {} pair.

Comment: actually, Oracle is forcing those downloads since they discontinued Java 6, but there may be other reasons to be stuck at old APIs.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same kind of problems lately, they were due to synchronization between tasks using the same non-synchronized variables (comment left for other people reading that :)).

In your case, as @Ralf mentioned, you're not waiting for the termination of the pool. So your `data2D` array is still filled with `null` (`data2D[k] == null` for all `k`), and you get an NPE when doing `data2D[k].length`.

I have tried to run the second version of your code and it throws NPE sometimes, after I run it 10 times. It's gone when calling `awaitTermination()`:

```
threadPool.shutdown();
try {
    while (!threadPool.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) ;
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

//Now collapse data2D into a 1D array
data1D = new int[numElements];
...
```

Comment: Thanks for following up on this at this later date.  +1 for trying to help.

Answer (score 1):

you are using `currIdx` many times in the Runnable. There are writes to `currIdx` from outside that `Runnable` since it is `static`. In the Runnable, better use local variable, maybe even make it `final` before entering the Runnable:

```
final int fCurrIdx = i;
threadPool.submit(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Random r = new Random();
        int[] data = new int[blockSize];
        for( int j=0; j<data.length; j++){
            data[j] = r.nextInt(255) * r.nextInt(255) * r.nextInt(255);
        }
        data2D[fCurrIdx] = data;
    }
});
```

In fact, I would create the new int[blockSize] locally, fill it, and assign it to data2D at the end.

Are you sure you need a new Random every time? Is there a reason to make currIdx (or others) static?

Comment: +1 for trying to help.  Thank you.  I took your advice and posted the revised code in a second edit to my posting above.  The code is still throwing the null pointer exception.  I posted the stack trace above as well.  The reason I am using static variables is that eclipse forces me to do so because main() is static.  I tried to get around this by putting the code in a separate method called from main(), but eclipse still demands everything be static. Help on that would be appreciated.  I call a new Random() every time to simulate a resource intensive algorithm for testing purposes.

Comment: I think the problem is that the threads with the new data have not yet returned when System.arraycopy(data2D[k], 0, data1D, startPos, data2D[k].length); tries to collapse them into a 1D array.

Comment: I think the problem is that the code needs a Future object to make sure that the ExecutorService has returned all its data slices before the various slices can be assembled in proper order into the final 1D array.  I just do not know the proper syntax required in this situation.

Comment: The static requirement is caused by not using an instance of ParallelArrays and implementing all methods non-static. 

Anyway, using Futures is not necessary, if you are not responding to individual jobs. After you call `threadPool.shutdown()`, the pool will not accept new submits, but it is of course not finished executing the submitted jobs. Use `threadPool.awaitTermination()` to make sure everything is finished.

Comment: Your problem actually comes from that: you're not waiting for the pool to finish so the `data2D` is still filled with `null` when you access it in your reconstruction loop.